# Can I manage “index.max_result_window “on a cluster-by-cluster basis?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I change the index.max_result_window value, I need to change it by index.
However, I want to change the index.max_result_window value of all indexes in the cluster.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the settings on all your indexes at once using the [`_all` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html#multi-index):

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index.max_result_window": "20000"
}
```